# ManyToMany Relationship "add-friend, remove-friend" in Django not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, manytomanyfield

How do I solve this many to many relationship problem. I am building a "ADD & REMOVE FRIENDS" system like Facebook. "if A is friend with B, then B is friend with A".

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

class Friend(models.Model):
    friend_user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

After selecting two users in Profile from Admin to create the relationship with the superuser and saved it.

When I access the shell to try the commands below, two issues come up:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import Friend
```

After instantiate:
`friend = Friend()`
When I type:
`friend`
The Shell return: 
`<Friend: Friend object (None)>`

I BELIEVE THE PROBLEM IS FROM THE LINE ABOVE, IT SHOULD NOT RETURN "NONE"

Also, when i try to add the relationship:
`friend.friend_user.add(User.objects.last())`
The Shell return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/fbook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 498, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/fbook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 795, in __init__
    (instance, self.pk_field_names[self.source_field_name]))
ValueError: "<Friend: Friend object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Any help would be much appreciate.

PS: I am using this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwpLCa79DUw&list=PLw02n0FEB3E3VSHjyYMcFadtQORvl1Ssj&index=54

Comment: You must save the `Friend` object before its `.id` property gets a value (which is why you must save it before including it in a m2m field also).

Comment: @thebjorn thank you I totally forgot

Comment: @thebjorn Please don't post answers as comments.  Doing so bypasses important Stack Exchange moderation systems, such as downvoting, and also deprives you of those sweet sweet answer points.

Comment: @AdamBarnes thank you for the information. In this case the OP simply skipped a line in the tutorial (or forgot), otherwise the question is well stated so I have upvoted (even with the all-caps line ;-). My comment was just a reminder, while an answer would need to be much more detailed -- without offering any added benefit to the OP. I participate in SO to help individual users more than support SO's grand agenda (although I do support the agenda -- at least in theory ;-)  Points are nice (I have a couple of them), and I'll upvote anyone that wishes to flesh out my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since "friends" is a many to many relationship between `Profile`s, you can bring your field back up into your Profile class and reference the same model with the string, `"self"`.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical